# OpenVPN connection on remote server blocks all incoming connections

Tags: linux, ssh, openvpn

I login into remote server (DigitalOcean) by SSH, and start OpenVPN client there. When this client gets connected to its endpoint, my SSH connection breaks.
After that I cannot connect to server or even ping it.
From DigitalOcean's internal VNC console I can see that host is online, OpenVPN connection is established and everything works.
ifconfig shows that both eth0 and tun0 are active.

Does anyone knows what happens to the connection? Why established OpenVPN connection breaks all connections?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken it sounds like you are logging into a server and then starting a VPN session from that server to somewhere else.  The problem I can see you might be having (without further clarification) is that you're not virtualizing the VPN connection.  Any time you have a machine establish a VPN tunnel that isn't in a virtual environment on a NAT connection, the VPN tunnel is going to take over the connection and completely segregate itself from any other traffic.  So you're still going to see activity off the NIC over the tunnel, but the connection will not be open to the external pings or other traffic you're using to check connectivity.

Again, I could be mistaken on this.  I'm not a VPN expert.